# how to draw the dataframe without the breaktime

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` loaded from a file. When i draw it, it shows all time with a straight line, but I don't need the middle of break time. How to do?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dateutil,os

str_today='2015-12-23'
pk_file='D:/20151223_SHSE.000001.pk'

start_tradetime=str_today+' 9:30:00';end_tradetime=str_today+' 15:00:00'
f_inx=pd.date_range(start_tradetime,end_tradetime,freq='5s')

symbol='SHSE.000001'

def load_tick_data(pk_file):
    fn=pk_file
    if os.path.exists(fn):
        return pd.read_pickle(fn)
    else:
        return None

symdata=load_tick_data(pk_file)
symdata.head(10)

plt.ion()
plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,1), (0,0), colspan=3,rowspan=3)
#draw
symdata['last_price'].asof(f_inx).plot(ax=ax1)
```

[how to remove the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgham.png)

[full ipython notebook runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuaXG.png)

Comment: Could you please upload a few periods of the data to a small file we can download to test with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to convert the `DateTimeIndex` to `string` representation as demonstrated below - the series jumps to show the 'missing' values for the trading break:[image]

```
df = pd.Series(data= np.random.random(size=400), index=pd.date_range(start=datetime(2015,1,1,9,0,0), freq='1Min', periods=400)).cumsum()
df.loc[datetime(2015, 1, 1, 11, 30, 0): datetime(2015, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0)] = np.nan
df.index = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M'))
df.dropna().plot.line()
```

Comment: That is not what I want.I hope they link tegother.

Comment: So how about `.dropna()` (assuming missing values cause the straight line)? It would help if you could show your data to get closer towards http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have tried      .dropna(),but there is a line......by the way ,how to upload my raw data file?

Comment: You could do `df.loc[time_before: time_after]` using timestamps before and after your line starts so one can see what type of data you have at these points in time. One would assume these are `np.nan` which may cause `matplolib` to interpolate hence the `.dropna` suggestion, but perhaps you are getting a constant for some other reason.

Comment: df.loc['11:30': '13:00'] has to be blank ,because there is not trading at that time.but after runing these,DF add data automatic:       f_inx=pd.date_range(start_tradetime,end_tradetime,freq='5s');symdata['last_price'].asof(f_inx)

Comment: I did the same thing as yours, but it just run out different result! I have uploaded the full session of ipython notebook, please check what's wrong,thinks! http://i.stack.imgur.com/iuaXG.png

Comment: I think you are missing the step in line 3 above to convert the remaining `timestamps` to `strings`, otherwise `pandas` will interpolate to create an even-space series.